# Does ONVIF provide an API for image retrieval from a network camera?

Tags: video, streaming, onvif

I am trying to retrieve images from a network camera. I can do it using MJPEG but somebody told me that I can do it using an ONVIF SDK. Is that true?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part of video retrieval, ONVIF basically redirects you to RTSP/RTP.

http://www.onvif.org/specs/stream/ONVIF-Streaming-Spec-v210.pdf

```
5
Live Streaming
  This section describes real-time streaming of video, audio and metadata. 
  There is no specific service associated with the real-time streaming. 
  The real-time configurations via Web Service commands are defined in the 
  Media Service and the ReceiverService.

5.1
Media stream protocol

5.1.1
Transport format
  Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP) is a media transfer protocol 
  (see Section 5.1.2). The following four sections describe RTP data transfer.
```